# using Zxing.Net Mobile for forms does is not recognize

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, zxing

I am new in Xamarin.Forms and I want use the bar code scaner by Zxing.
however I install the plugin form nuget:
1)ZXing.Net.Mobile for Forms
2) ZXing.Net.Mobile. -> install it since I read somewhere it would help my problem but its not.

as far as I understood I need to add this line: to the Android project in main Activity

However alotugh I install the packages I am still getting an error of:
The type or namespace name 'Andorid' does not exist in the namespace 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  ScannerZXing.Android

what can I do? (perofrm clean and rebuild for the project didn't help)

also would like to add that it is added in the referecnes of the projects.

Thanks for the ansewrs.

Comment: Did you also install the NuGet on your Android project?

Comment: Based on you newest question, you've solved this issue?

Comment: yes I reinnstall it using overwrite on android and it helped

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the reason was that I installed only ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms. After installing ZXing.Net.Mobile it`s gone. (two libraries need to be installed)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** After trying to run the project I discovered that you actually need both Nuget Packages

**Previous:** Just in case anyone had the same issue as me there are actually two ZXing.Net.Mobile packages both of which by Redth. They both have the exact same description as well unfortunately. I tried the first one which at the time of this writing had the most downloads... however it produced the error as described. By uninstalling and reinstalling the second I resolved the issue:
[image]